# how to override bootstrap col-md and other properties for links in <a>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment

[image: Image Explaining my problem]

As i have posted an image we can see that due to bootstrap properties it allocating the full box for the link when seeing via inspect element

how to remove that whole thing and only keep the limit where the text is over i,e instead of allocating the whole line i want that box to be over at the last character of word

Any helps appreciated ! :)

This is my code :

```
<footer class="text-left row foot-div bench">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="600ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div class="text-uppercase footer-main-title">Professional Bodies</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="http://www.ieindia.info" target="_blank"><li>IE</li></a>
        <a href="http://www.iete.org" target="_blank"><li>IETE</li></a>
        <a href="http://www.isteonline.in" target="_blank"><li>ISTE</li></a>
        <a href="http://www.csi-india.org" target="_blank"><li>CSI</li></a>
        <a href="http://www.ieee.org" target="_blank"><li>IEEE</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="600ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div class="text-uppercase footer-main-title">Campus Facilities</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>atm.html"><li>ATM</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>ghostel.html"><li>Girls Hostel</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>Newpdf/digipage.htm"><li>Digital Library</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>dispensary.html"><li>Medical Dispensary</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>sportgm.html"><li>Sports & Gymkhana</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>av.html"><li>Audio - Video Section</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="600ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div class="text-uppercase footer-main-title">Important Links</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="http://mail.sipnaengg.ac.in"><li>Mail Login</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>login.html"><li>HOD Login</li></a>
        <a href="http://www.dte.org.in" target="_blank"><li>DTE, Mumbai</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>T&P Feedback</li></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><li>AICTE, New Delhi</li></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><li>random data</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>spltp.html"><li>Training Programmes</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>ietebuild.html"><li>IETE Amravati Centre</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>wgs.html"><li>Women's Greivence Cell</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="600ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div class="text-uppercase footer-main-title">Student Activities</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>nss.html"><li>N.S.S</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>vidyotan.html"><li>Vidyotan</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>innovater.html"><li>Innovator</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>CSIchapter.html"><li>CSI Chapter</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>ETSO.html"><li>IETE Forum</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>natureclub"><li>Nature Club</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>sports.html"><li>Sports</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>newpdf/NewsMedia15/"><li>Newsmedia</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>newpdf/ISF/"><li>IETE Student Forum</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>IEEE/"><li>IEEE Student Chapter</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="600ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div class="text-uppercase footer-main-title">Downloads</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>Newpdf/Mand_Discl2015.pdf"><li>Mandatory Disclosure 2014-15</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>Newpdf/Documents.pdf"><li>AICTE-DTE Disc Certificates</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>parentmeet.html"><li>Parents Meet</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>photogallery_new15.htm"><li>Image Gallery</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>videogallery"><li>Video Gallery</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>msit.html"><li>Microsoft IT-Curriculum<br />Syllabus & Fee Structure</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the css code :

```
.foot-div
{
    padding: 5px;
}
.foot-div div div
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #337ab7;
}
.foot-div div ul
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.foot-div div ul li
{
    list-style-type: square;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.foot-div div ul a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.foot-div div ul a:hover
{
    color: #2eb48f;
}
```

Comment: did you test inline-block?

Comment: yups perhaps.. Where and how to add it ? i have tried a lots of logic and codes but none are working even tried inline CSS :(

Comment: via inline-block,you can use width and height  that you want. if you fiddle your code, maybe i can say you.

Comment: Nopes didn't work, got jumbled moreover

Answer (score 0):

Your list items are wrapped in links. Try to do the opposite. Wrap each link in the list item. Use

```
<li><a href="">Text</a></li>
```

instead of

```
<a href=""><li>Text</li></a>
```

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav I need to see your CSS and HTML. Snapshot is not enough to understand how your page is arranged.